# How to scroll to an adapter in ConcatAdapter in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am really not sure how to scroll to a particular adapter in ConcatAdapter.
I have multiple adapters being concatenated in a recycler view

1. Adapter A
2. Adapter B
3. Adapter C
4. Adapter D
5. Adapter E

Now when the user taps on a button I need to scroll and navigate to Adapter C.
Not sure how I can do that in ConcatAdapter case. I am trying to search online not getting much help for this case. Appreciate any suggestions/inputs

Comment: I don't see a built in solution in docs, I guess you have to add size of adapters A and B which would give you position of first item of adapter C then it's just a matter of scrolling there.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of sorted adapters and scroll to the desired one:

```
val sortedAdapters = listOf(adapterA, adapterB, adapterC, adapterD, adapterE)
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(sortedAdapters.indexOf(adapterC as? Adapter<*>))
```